# Chef - If elsif statements

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Trying to do something rather simple in Chef but can't seem to get right. I know it would be easier to use the IIS cookbook but long story short it's not available at this time.

Trying to run a `if` `elsif` from the Attributes file like this. But the `if node[:domain]` section doesn't seem to run, it just ignores it or it's not being validated, I can't tell. The default section works

```
      if node[:platform] == 'windows'

    default['WebSiteCreation']['Dir'] = 'D:\Websites'
    default['WebSiteCreation']['AppPool'] = 'MySite'
    end

if node[:domain] == 'Dev.com'

    default['WebSiteCreation']['HostHeader'] = 'Dev'

elsif node[:domain] == 'Test.com'

    default['WebSiteCreation']['HostHeader'] = 'Test'

elsif node[:domain] == 'Preprod.com'

    default['WebSiteCreation']['HostHeader'] = 'PreProd'

elsif node[:domain] == 'prod.com'

    default['WebSiteCreation']['HostHeader'] = 'Prod'

    else
end
```

However, when I call anything referenced from if node section as a variable in the recipe blank is passed, so it can't be defined.

I've tried moving the code to the recipe, no effect.

What am I doing wrong....

Comment: Are you sure that the `node[:domain]` values start with uppercase letters? Maybe it's `"dev.com"` (just guessing)

Comment: put something in the `else` then

Comment: If you have a chef node to test, run ohai, grep for domain and check what value does it return. Use case statements instead of long if else blocks which will make code look neat

Comment: @slashpai - Thank you, the Ohai command found that it was the case that was causing the issue, much appreciated!

Comment: @Richard Dakin Good to know that :), I have added as answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a chef node to test run ohai, grep for domain and check what value does it return. Update your comparison based on that. Also it is better to use case statements instead of long if else blocks which will make code look neat

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine from a Ruby and Chef PoV, most likely the issue is that your domain is not what you think it is.